# Plotting these functions without encountering overflow errors

Tags: plotting

I want to plot the iterates of the function $f(x)=13xe^{-x}$ up to power $4$. So I am using the code `Plot[{f[x], h[x], j[x], g[x], x}, {x, -0.3, 4}]` where $f,h,j,g$ are the first, second, third, and fourth iterate of the function respectively. This sort of works, but overflow errors are thrown in my face:

[image]

This is probably because the iterates get pretty complicated and probably give very large values. So, is there a better way to plot these functions?

Comment: By iterates, do you mean `h[x] == f[f[x]]` etc.? What is the code you use to define `f,h,j,g`?

Comment: The trouble's coming from the left. Try `Plot[Rest[NestList[13 # Exp[-#] &, x, 4]], {x, -0.03, 4}, Evaluated -> True]` instead.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by J.M., the problem is with the negative x range.  Particularly with your `g[x]=f[f[f[f[x]]]]`, which evaluates to

```
28561 E^(-x - 13 E^-x x - 169 E^(-x - 13 E^-x x) x - 
  2197 E^(-x - 13 E^-x x - 169 E^(-x - 13 E^-x x) x) x) x
```

This very quickly approaches the `$MaxNumber` for negative values,

```
$MaxNumber
f[f[f[f[-.06591]]]]
(* 1.605216761933662*10^1355718576299609 *)
(* -5.992559179678360*10^1344011404161905 *)
```

So you can either truncate the negative plotting range, or just use `Quiet` to suppress the error,

```
Plot[{f[x], f[f[x]], f[f[f[x]]], f[f[f[f[x]]]], x}, {x, -0.3, 4}, 
  Evaluated -> True] // Quiet
```

[image]